# Having multiple image with same hover over effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i currently have multiple images on a page, however when i want over hover effect on the one that is being hovered over. Where the page has more than 12 images, one way is to replicate this code 12 times, with an id but is there a more efficient way:

```
$("img").hover(function () {
    $("img").addClass("transition");
}, function () {
    $("img").removeClass("transition");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to apply hover effect only on currently hovered image and not on the other images, use `$(this)` as shown below :-

```
$("img").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("transition");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("transition");
});
```

Comment: How about if instead i use $("img").hover i use a div but still want to have the effect on the image inside the div as there maybe text within the div that i want the same effect

Comment: @jsg...as far i get what you want to say..you want images inside div a hover effect... so in that case you can use `$('div img')` as selector.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `in/out` hover handler to toggle the class:

```
$("img").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("transition");
});
```

But be aware, this could be done using only CSS with pseudo class `:hover` if your goal is just to apply transition to these images.